# Word for changing or shortening or abbreviating a given name

Tags: single-word-requests

I came to this  website when I was looking for a particular word - but did not use a thesaurus because I could not think of a good synonym.

Instead I searched for

> Word for changing or shortening or abbreviating a given name

After amending the original search to try to get what I am seeking & so far what is here is the nearest but I KNOW there is a word for exactly that which I seek.

THIS is getting to be a long entry and unlikely to attract any, let alone many readers.

I am writing in England and am 66 years old - the word 'fanny' in my era is slang for the most intimate part of a woman's body, yet means other things in other versions of English, and is indeed used as a woman's nickname in England on some occasions. So what I am after is something about renaming akin to a nickname - I had hoped it will come back to me but it has not yet!

All this was prompted by the sight of a product supplied in a can - I am not sure where from - that contains what I know as tuna fish but is called 'Fanny' and therefore if it were seen in a British provision store might produce a smirk or embarrassed giggles because some, such as me, would consider it rude - I have said too much.

My wife could not help, she compared it to 'Betty' as an alternative to Elizabeth - but I do not think that is quite the same - as Betty - to me seems - a definite abbreviation of Elizabeth.

I may have posted this in the wrong place - I am happy for it to be repositioned perhaps with a more accurate subject line - BUT I just want to recall that blessed word and improve my grammar!

I imagine my sentence might be -

> In the family she is known as Fanny
>   because that is how we have XXXXXXXXXXX her formal name of
>   Ermintrude/Glorianna/(or whatever)

Comment: "Although her formal name is [X], we have _nicknamed_ her [Y]." I realize others mentioned "nickname", but this is how I would rephrase your sentence to use it as a verb.  (By the way, as an American, I wouldnt touch a can of _Spotted Dick_ with a ten-foot pole!)

Comment: It is poor spotted dick that comes in a can - it is best home made & I  remember from school dinner days in the 1950s a& 60s

Not something we have in my family as we have all eaten too many pies &  puddings in the past - but a relatively cheap & easy item to make for several hundred at a time basicallya flour mix with dried fruit added & then custard poured over - the sort of thing that was manaegable in the UK in the post war years when filling children was more a priority than the quality of nutrition..

I am frightened of this stack place - I go off topic & often attract reprimands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[hypocorism:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocorism)** (also known as a pet name or calling name), is a shorter or diminutive form of a word or given name, for example, when used in more intimate situations as a nickname or term of endearment.

*James --> Jimmy*
*Charles --> Charlie*

Comment: Thank you to Jimmy - I am sorry I did not see his answer before today.

Answer (score 8):

You are probably looking for a word **diminutive** which is a noun:

> *A diminutive word is a "cute" version of a regular word, "Maggie" is the diminutive of "Margaret."* <sup>per [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/diminutive)</sup>

So your "have XXXXXXXXXXX her formal name" = "have formed a diminutive of her formal name."

Answer (score 5):

You named it yourself, ***nickname*** is the term you're looking for.

> ***nickname***
>
> *(n.)* a familiar form of a proper name, as Jim for James and Peg for Margaret [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nickname)
>
> *(v.)* to give a nickname to [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nickname)

Comment: Not to begrudge you the upvotes but the OP does mention "nickname" in his question: **So what I am after is something about renaming akin to a nickname**

Comment: @Mari-LouA I overlooked that fact actually. I've just updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickname) suggests the following verbs: **abbreviate**, **modify**, **contract**, and **shorten**. Alternatively, the verb [**truncate**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/truncate) could be used, which means to chop the head or the tail of something.

> **Abbreviation or modification**
>
> A *nickname* can be a *shortened* or *modified* variation on a person's real name.
>
> - Contractions of longer names: Margaret to *Greta*.
> - Initials using the first letters of a person's first and last name.
> - Dropping letters: With many nicknames, one or more letters, usually R, are dropped: *Fanny* from Frances, *Walt* from Walter.
> - Phonetic spelling : Sometimes a nickname is created through the phonetic spelling of a name: *Len* from Leonard

But perhaps the OP is thinking of the expression **pet name**, which isn't the name you give to a pet but to a dear friend, or a member of the family. It usually has no bearing with the owner's given or first name (once called *Christian name*).

Oxford Dictionaries tells us is:

> [pet name](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pet-name)
>   A name that is used instead of someone’s usual first name to express fondness or familiarity
>
> - *And ‘Pinky’ is a name (more of a pet name, really) that both men and women choose or are given*.

Comment: Thanks to all - I have either invented something I thought I knew that never existed  or still not found how to ask for the term that I seek - I am sorry to have caused work for contributors and hope there is benefit for some readers in what is been undertaken in an attempt to assist me.

I deserve only down votes and no up votes for my effort - memory is an asset and yet at time a curse - especially for a dyspraxic person like me who can be certain something is 'in there somewhere' but just cannot grasp it - because it happens so frequently - I am truly sorry.

Comment: @Andrew_S_Hatton hey, no problem. I'm sorry I didn't reply earlier, must have missed your comment. If one or some of the answers helped you that's great.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement Mari-Lou A (I have yet to learn how to tag other contributors)

Comment: @Andrew_S_Hatton you need to preface a username with @ if that person is not the author of an answer or question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I must have my StackExchange settings adjusted incorrectly as I did not get an email notice I had received a response or been tagged

Comment: Thanks @mari-Lou I had not before appreciated that Frances is a substantive given name for the hypocorism of Fanny, I am however familiar with Franny for the male version Francis.

It was in Wikipedia , all the time, thank you for the comment, I am content, and now have found what I was seeking.

Comment: @Andrew_S_Hatton My pleasure, glad you found it useful

Comment: Gosh 16,000 - views - it may have been poorly expressed but an issue that others either also struggle with or have an interest in.

Thanks for all the interest - I think my best skill is asking questions - but as a dyslexic and dyspraxic - finding the correct word to use in a question, that is meaningful to others can be a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

The hypocoristic form of a name is, as mentioned above, a diminutive form of a name (James becomes Jim or Jimmie, Elizabeth becomes Liz, Beth, or Bettie, Robert becomes Bob or Rob or Bobbie...) but can also refer to a pet name (which may not derive directly from the given name).  A sobriquet is a nickname or pet name and requires no direct lineage to the given name (I have a friend named Howard but everyone calls him Skip).  I know this is a LATE post but... just throwing it out there.